# Why cp1256 collation is not 1 byte in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, collation

I've read an article that cp1256 collation takes 1 byte for Arabic characters, but when I created an index on the column that was cp1256 with type of varchar(900), only 767 characters picked up for index purposes:

> CREATE TABLE `col` (
>    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>    arabic varchar(900) CHARACTER SET cp1256 NOT NULL,
>    PRIMARY KEY (id),
>    KEY (arabic(767)
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB;

Arabic varchar(900) truncated to (767) for my index.
Why is that the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a limit of the InnoDB engine. It cannot index more than 767 bytes (for a single column)

See the manual:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-restrictions.html

> By default, an index key for a single-column index can be up to 767 bytes 
>   ... 
>   When you attempt to specify an index prefix length longer than allowed, the length is silently reduced to the maximum length